# how to make select folder dialog box?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

How can I make the form field type `folder` which opens the dialog box and able to select the folder.

```
<field
  name="folder"
  type="folder"
  label="Folder"
  description="Select the folder"
  required="true"
  default=""
/>
```

There is already media type which selects the image from the folder and folderlist which shows backend folderlist but I wanted to select a folder of images.

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think what you want exists. In any case, the all the Joomla standard form field types can be found here: http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [field type `folderlist`](http://docs.joomla.org/Folderlist_form_field_type) to get a list of folder in a specified directory on Joomla 2.5+.

The limiting factors of this form element are that you must provide an initial directory e.g. (`/images`) and it doesn't provide a mechanism to drill down, so if you start in `/images/` your user won't be shown or have a means to select `/images/module-art/front-page` for example.

Syntax is pretty standard.

```xml
<field
    name="myfolder"
    type="folderlist"
    default=""
    label="Select a folder"
    directory="images"
    filter=""
    exclude=""
    stripext="" />
```